# Cannot Create Subinterface on C3650 L3 Switch

Tags: cisco-catalyst, layer3

We have WS-C3650-24TS Catalyst L3 switch. I am trying to create a sub-interface on the ports but cannot make it work as the following error shows. Is there something I'm missing?

Sorry, newbie here.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try ‘no switchport’ first

Comment: I tried, then used the same command. But I got the same error.

Comment: Is this sub-interface creation switch specific (C3650), license specific (ipservices), or IOS specific (16.6.8)? Or is there some required command/configuration that I might be missing? Thanks

Comment: Post the output of `show int gi 1/1/1 switch`

Comment: Please post output as text, not as images, and use `{` and `}` to use prefomatted text.

Comment: On switches, you create SVIs, and you set the interfaces to trunks. You can specify which VLANs are on the trunks. It is not like a router interface where you use subinterfaces for the VLANs,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subinterfaces are used on routers and they can be used on some L3 switches. You need to configure the physical interface as a *routed port* or *L3 port* using `no switchport`, `exit` its config and *then* you can configure a subinterface.

On the 3650 series, VLAN subinterfaces on routed ports are not supported:
https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3650/software/release/3se/int_hw_components/configuration_guide/b_int_3se_3650_cg/b_int_3se_3650_cg_chapter_010.html

> A routed port behaves like a regular router interface, except that it
> does not support VLAN subinterfaces.

Of course, the physical interface should also be enabled: `no shutdown`

Alternatively, use a switched interface and a VLAN with a *switch virtual interface* (SVI).

Comment: I did that as an alternative, that is working fine with us. But why can I not create this sub-interface?